# sqlite3 works in through client but doesn't work in python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, discord.py

Im trying to delete a row in python however when i try to in python nothing works. However when I try using it in the sqlite client it does work.

here is the sqlite client:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbZ1Q.jpg

here is the python version:

```
             
    @commands.command(aliases=['r'])
    async def rmeove(self, ctx, user:discord.User):
        player = user.id
        if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
            db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute(f"DELETE FROM main WHERE Players= {int(player)};")
            db.commit
            cursor.close
            db.close
            await ctx.channel.send("a")
            print(user.id)
```

when i try to execute it through python, it does not delete it not shows any error

Comment: There could be two reasons why your code does nothing and produces no error message. (1) Your `if`-clause is false. To check this, put a trace `print()` call to make sure that the `if` test is doing what you expect. (2) The value delivered by `int(player)` is not what you expect.  It is not an error in SQL to have `delete from table where key=nonexistent`. But it won't do anything either. Again, put a trace `print()` call to show you what the SQL you are constructing really looks like.

Comment: Are you really missing the ()'s in your source?  (As in if your code is db.commit ... this doesn't actually do anything but also doesn't error out (if you typed it in the Python REPL, you'd get back that it was a function... are you coming from Ruby perhaps (where you don't need parens for parameter-less functions)?